# Постраничная навигация 1-10,10-20,20-30

Tags: php, mysql

> Получаю count(id) пример **60**

**Как сделать так чтобы вывести в виде:**
1-10,10-20,20-30,30-40,40-50,50-60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не прав, но есть велосипед на [webew](http://webew.ru/articles/5510.webew) и я сказал бы очень даже не плохой.

> Страницы: предыдущая 1-20 21-40 41-60 61-80 81-100 следующая

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$pageSize = 10;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 0;
$pages = ceil($count / $pageSize);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ' . $page . ', ' . $pageSize);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
//вывод записей
}
foreach($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
   if($page === $i {
      echo '<b><a href="?page=' . ($i - 1) . '">' . $i . '</a></b> ';
   } else {
      echo '<a href="?page=' . ($i - 1) . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
   }
}
```

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 где то косяк немогу найти хD

Comment: @alias, нужно вывести постраничную навигацию в формате 1-10,10-20,20-30,30-40,40-50,50-60, а у вас получается 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: echo '<a href="?page=' . ($i - 1) . '">' . ($i * 10) . '</a> ';

Answer (score 1):

Может быть что-нибудь из этого Вам подойдет:

```
<?php

$records = 65;
$on_page = 10;

$page_count = ceil($records / $on_page);


/**
 * Вариант под Ваши условия
 */
for ($i = 0; $i < $page_count; $i++) {
    $int_begin = ($i * 10);
    if ($int_begin == 0) {
        $int_begin = 1;
    }

    $int_end = (($i + 1) * 10);
    if ($int_end > $records) {
        $int_end = $records;
    }

    echo "[" . $int_begin . "-" . $int_end . "]";
}

/**
 * И, как мне кажется, более правильный вариант. 
 * Т.к. если первая страница оканчивается 10 записью, то вторая должна начинаться с 11
 */
for ($i = 0; $i < $page_count; $i++) {

    $int_end = (($i + 1) * 10);
    if ($int_end > $records) {
        $int_end = $records;
    }

    echo "[" . ($i * 10 + 1) . "-" . $int_end . "]";
}
```